# url_path is missing for products in category-view

Tags: magento-1.9, category-view

product attribute `url_path` is missing for all products in category view, but it is present in product lists/grids.

This has an effect on review links, they have empty urls.

I can't get my head around, where is that defined or being loaded?

```
catalog/category/view => Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction
```

calls somewhere in a template

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::getUrlPath
```

and the result is `null`, coming from

```
$product->getData('url_path')
```

Comment: Can you paste your collection code?

Comment: it's probably default, I don't even know where to find that code.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem in the MageWorx/SeoSuite module. There is a configuration setting called "*Product Reviews Friendly URLs*", which expects `url_path` to be present in the collection. You can change the attribute in your catalog_eav_attribute table:

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute AS ca, eav_attribute AS a
SET
    ca.used_in_product_listing=1
WHERE
    ca.attribute_id=a.attribute_id
    AND a.attribute_code = 'url_path'
```